# How do I access a non-@observable field via polymer bindings with dart2js in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Seth Ladd's Polymer.dart examples are awesome and really helpful. The [observable_list](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/tree/master/web/observable_list) example appends `DateTime` instances to an `ObservableList timestamps`. Although `DateTime` does not extend `Observable`, modifying [my_element.html](https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/observable_list/my_element.html) to access a field on

`{{ts in timestamps}}`

works when running in the Dart VM. For example, changing

`<li>{{ts}}</li>`

to

`<li>{{ts.second}}</li>`

will access the `DateTime.seconds` field when on the Dart VM. However, when dart2js compiles the app to javascript, access to fields in the Polymer expression is broken. An exception `Uncaught Error: RangeError: value 0` is thrown in this case, or more generally `NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol(...)'` for the fieldname is thrown (see example [here](https://gist.github.com/mmaz/7581228))

If a class extends `Observable` then access to `@observable` fields works inside of Polymer expressions after compiling to Javascript (changing the class `MyRow` [in this example](https://gist.github.com/mmaz/7581228#file-myrow-dart) to `extends Observable` does not throw an exception in javascript).

What can I do when I am unable to add annotations to external classes like `DateTime`? Is this just a current bug in dart2js generation, or will the Polymer.dart spec forbid reading fields out of non-observable classes? Previously, `web_ui` successfully accessed fields from our [dart-protobuf](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protobuf) generated classes after compiling to javascript, so I'm hoping this use-case will gain support in Polymer.dart too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, dart2js tries to tree-shake and minify code, and it doesn't know that some of the code is used from a polymer expression (which uses mirrors internally to interpret the expressions). Very likely what happened here is that dart2js is either deleting the non-observable fields or minifying them in a way that they are not reflectable.

To fix this, you can indicate that these fields need to be preserved and used via mirrors. In polymer we provide the @reflectable annotation for this purpose. (@observable also implies @reflectable, that's why it works when you have @observable). So you can use that in the `MyRow` case.

Fields from types in the core libraries can work also if they become reflectable. In this case it is a bit harder to express because you can't modify the original code to add this annotation. Instead you can use the @MirrorsUsed annotation to override the default behavior on these core types, or avoid using these fields inside polymer-expressions by hiding them inside @reflectable getters or in filters that are written directly in Dart code.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks! Regarding my intended use, do you feel that perhaps adding an option to dart-protoc-plugin to produce @reflectable getter annotations would be valuable? I could file an issue (and maybe a pull request eventually, if there's only minor interest)